# JS issue with creating an array copy

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to add properties and flatmap and make changes to the array
without changing the original array(data).
I'm using this method in 2 places from a one dispatch call in vue js when i'm passing the data from parent tp children.

- When i'm using the method for the first time every thing is ok, but when i'm using the array the second time in different child component :* it seems like the first it did made changes to the original data
  and i don't want to make any changes to the original array.
  (JS AND VUE JS & TS)

```
public mapJson(data:any){
            let copyData:any = [...data]

            const newObjects:Array<MetaObject> = [];
            const cb = (e) => {
            let elemnt: any = {...e};

            if(elemnt.item.parentId.value === 0){
                elemnt.item.parentId.value = null;
            }
      
                if(elemnt.item.idOnScene){
                    let split = elemnt.item.idOnScene.split("|");
                    elemnt.item.modelId = elemnt.item.id.value;
                    elemnt.item.id.value = split[2];
                    elemnt.item.name = split[1];
                    elemnt.item.type = split[0];
                }
                else{
                    elemnt.item.modelId = elemnt.item.id.value;
                }

            let newMeta = {
                id: elemnt.item.id.value,
                name: elemnt.item.name,
                type: elemnt.item.name,
                parent: elemnt.item.parentId.value,
                modelId: elemnt.item.modelId
            }
            newObjects.push(newMeta);

            e.children && e.children.forEach(cb);
        }
        copyData.forEach(cb);

        const newData : Metadata = {
            id: "",
            projectId: "2GcXDGLMXA_8_$wW69Hy7E",
            author: "",
            createdAt: "2019-01-21T13:24:08",
            schema: "IFC2X3",
            creatingApplication: "20181011_1500(x64) - Exporter 18.4.0.0 - Alternate UI 18.4.0.0",
            metaObjects: newObjects
        };

        return newData;
        }
```

Comment: What *is* `data`? `[...data]` is only a *shallow* copy, so if it contains anything mutable you may still have problems.

Comment: Install 'lodash.clonedeep' package and try using that to clone your array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))
Solved the issue